# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =2) during XML parsing

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser

```
 #import "LocationParser.h"

 @implementation LocationParser

-(LocationParser *)initXMLParser
{
 self=[super init];
 if (self)
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    self.parsingArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:appDelegate.presenceArray];
    //parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]init]; // this was the wrong place to declare. 
    [self parseArrayofPresence];
}
   return self;
}
-(void)parseArrayofPresence
{
 for (NSData *data in _parsingArray)
{     NSLog(@"presence data for parsing is :- %@",data);//this shows the data in NSData form.
      parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:data]; // this solves the problem
 }
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];   // this gets highlighted showing EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

 }
```

This is the AppDelegate Class where i get the data.

```
   - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
   {
       if ([presence status]!= nil) {
      _presenceData = [[presence status] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//convert presence to NSData
      [_presenceArray addObject:_presenceData]; // add NSData to a mutable array
    locationParser = [[LocationParser alloc]initXMLParser];  //initialising location parser class
   }
```

Comment: Have you used the delegate NSXMLDelegate in your .h class?

Comment: yes .. i have done that.

Comment: why you are parsing it inside the for loop?

Comment: i need to parse the content from array...wat's the other way?

Comment: AFAIK you can Parse only 1 xml at at time as its a asynchronous method..  Try waiting for the completion of your first XML parsing before starting the another 1..

Comment: where are you setting the url or xml for parsing?

Comment: the problem is I have an array With NSData content in it...so i was trying to read the array....i don't have a url to set...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving out your
`[parser setDelegate:self];
  [parser parse];`

out of for Loop.. BY the way why are you doing that in for loop?

Comment: YOu have not added any data to XML parser class? what data its going to parse anyway? use `[[NSXMLparser alloc]initwithData:data]`

Comment: how can i do it with an array of NSData

Comment: `parser = [[NSXMLparser alloc]initwithData:data];                [parser setDelegate:self]; [parser parse]` but your implementation seems wrong to me as if You are using a for loop you need to have a mechanishm to complete the first parsing than start with another 1..

Comment: now since the parser is showing the output, well only part of it...do you think there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Do some brainStorming on this might you will surely found a better answer.